# Android: I am populating listview with list. List is populated by getting value via parsing

Tags: android, android-xml

here is code which is creating adapter and populating list. I have also given the values that list contained.

```
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, temp);
           // temp is list
            lst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

what I think I have problem in structure of list which is not compatible with listview kindly provide effective way to do this 
The values in temp are

```
 12-01 10:58:51.161: I/System.out(521): list has value  [
 12-01 10:58:51.161: I/System.out(521):         asdfasdf
 12-01 10:58:51.161: I/System.out(521):         asdf
 12-01 10:58:51.161: I/System.out(521):         cat5
 12-01 10:58:51.180: I/System.out(521):         asdf
 12-01 10:58:51.180: I/System.out(521):       , 
 12-01 10:58:51.190: I/System.out(521):         asdf
 12-01 10:58:51.190: I/System.out(521):         fdf
 12-01 10:58:51.190: I/System.out(521):         cat5
 12-01 10:58:51.190: I/System.out(521):         zxcv
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):       , 
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         dasdasd
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         adsd
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         cat3
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         asdf
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):       , 
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         sad 
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         de
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         cat1
 12-01 10:58:51.200: I/System.out(521):         asdf
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):       , 
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         asdasd
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         asd
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         cat2
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         zxcv
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):       , 
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         asdasdf
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         fdsfsdfdfsf
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         cat4 +
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):         zxcv
 12-01 10:58:51.210: I/System.out(521):       ]
```

Comment: "structure of list which is not compatible with listview" .what does it means?can you provide more explanation ?

Comment: What does "temp" represent?

Comment: What is the data type of temp list?

Comment: List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();